# '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)' after item added to array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I have a tableView that starts off with two empty arrays (storageData & descripData - as a user has not yet added any items). Now when my user adds an item (a title, a description and a photo) and refreshes the tableView, I get the error:

*'-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)'*

That said, I'm not sure as to why. See code below; thanks!

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self.storageData count] > 0 && self.descripData.count > 0)
    {
        return [self.storageData count];
    }
    else
        return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *DoctorsTableIdentifier = @"StorageItemTableViewCell";

    StorageItemTableViewCell *cell = (StorageItemTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DoctorsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)

        {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StorageItemTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

   if (self.storageData.count > 0 && self.descripData.count > 0) {

        noitemsView.hidden = YES;

            NSDictionary *tmp = [self.storageData objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(long)indexPath.row]];


       [[cell itemName] setText:(NSString *)[tmp objectForKey:@"title"]];

              NSString *title = [tmp objectForKey:@"title"];
            [[cell itemName] setText:title];

            NSDictionary *node = [self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [[cell itemDescrip] setText:[node objectForKey:@"body"]];
            NSLog(@"%@", self.descripData);

            NSString *secondLink = [[self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"photo"];

            [cell.itemPhoto sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:secondLink]];

            NSLog(@"%@",secondLink);


              }

    else {
        noitemsView.hidden = NO;
    }
    return cell;

              }
```

Comment: in what line does the error occur?

Comment: @luk2302 The console highlights the error at the following line:  NSDictionary *node = [self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Have you tried logging what `self.descripData` contains? especially if it contains more than one element as the error suggests it should do.

Comment: @luk2302 Technically self.descripData contains both the description and a photo, while storageData simply contains the title. I assume that's why I keep encountering the beyond bounds message? That said, I have one user with multiple items already stored, and no crash occurs. I only get the crash when a user tries to add one item to an array with 0 items; the crash does not occur when a user adds 1 item to an array with existing items.

Comment: ...and which line dropped that romantic exception to you?

Comment: Having two arrays will cause an issue.  Instead create a custom object containing all the data you want to track and hold a single array of those custom objects.

Comment: you should think about a better structure for your objects, storing everything in multiple arrays and dictioniarys is very error prone.

Comment: @trojanfoe You're totally right. Just merged the data into one object; crisis averted. Not sure why I didn't think of that earlier on; thank you!

Comment: You are generating `[self.storageData count]` rows and you are trying to access to `self.descripData` using the other array count reference. Are you sure that `descripData` is synchronized with `storageData`. Cleanest solution is also replace `if (self.storageData.count > 0 && self.descripData.count > 0)` with `if (self.storageData.count > indexPath.row && self.descriptData.count > indexPath.row)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closer on self.descripData.count, because in numberOrRowsInSection you returned the [self.storageData count]. But seems that self.storageData.count > self.descripData.count, so you are trying to get object beyond self.descripData bounds. So simple.

Comment: Ahhhh makes sense. Put data into one array instead of two (threw everything into descripData); now returning descripData in numberofRowsInSection. Crisis averted :) Thx!

Answer (score 0):

In your `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method,you return `storageData`'s count if `storageData.count > 0` and `descripData.count > 0` .

And as you have said it crashed on this line `NSDictionary *node = [self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

It seems that `self.storageData.count > self.descripData.count`.Please check if the two arrays' count is the same or not.